# AND operator in *ngIf in angular evaluates to true while it should not

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I have the following inside an `ngx-datatable` in angular:

```
<button ngbDropdownItem 
 *ngIf="(row['REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE_NO'] == 5 && ['ENROLL_TAX_PAYER'] | authority)">
                            {{ 'M.SUBMIT_FOR_SYSTEM_CHECK' | translate }}
  </button>
```

in the above code the `ENROLL_TAX_PAYER`condition evaluates to true it should do so because the user has that permission.
the `row['REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE_NO'] == 5` part evaluates to false if if check it individually by `{{row['REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE_NO'] == 5}}`and that actually should. The problem is that when combined, it evaluates to true and the button gets displayed while it should not. what am I doing wrong?.
When I make it like `(row['REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE_NO'] == 5) && (['ENROLL_TAX_PAYER'] | authority)` it works though. Is it not supposed to work in the first case too? I mean since `REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE_NO` is NOT five and the operator is `AND` the condition should evaluate as false.

Answer (score 2):

Without brackets your condition is seen this way by TS. It first solves the pipe and then the &&.

```
row['REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE_NO'] == 
(5 && (['ENROLL_TAX_PAYER'] | authority))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but ENROLL_TAX_PAYER is not part of the row, it just any array being passed to pip to check if the user has  those permissions.

Comment: I adjusted my answer.

Comment: bro we can't pass 5 along with an array combined with & operator to a pip. it should have given me an error if so. So i don't think it to be that way.

Comment: Also where did that OR come from? bcz i have not used it anywhere.

Comment: Well, have a word with the makers of JavaScript, ESLint and TSLint: `console.log(!!(5 && []));` returns `true`. And no warning appears. Nor while coding and/or compiling, neither at runtime. So it is perfectly okay. - - - 
Sorry for the OR. My bad, now I see that this is a pipe. I re-adjusted my answer. But still, your problem here is, that Typescript says `row['REQUEST_STATUS_TYPE_NO'] == (5 && ['ENROLL_TAX_PAYER'])`. So you have to use the brackets in this case. Otherwise your code/intention is misunderstood by TS.